# How to return the Key of Node in AVL Tree according to specific value? (C++)

Tags: c++, avl-tree

I am now learning Data Structures, and I want to practice AVL Tree. I copied the codes from GeeksForGeeks, and I got some problems returning the key of a specific node.

The program first read a CSV file, then insert the nodes. After inserting the nodes, I want to retrieve the Node's key where phoneNo = "2-173-423-8400". I successfully found the key using pre-order traversal, but I could not return the value to main().  What is the problem? How to fix it?

Expected return value: 8056147046

Actual return value: 4306440216

[image: Result image]

main.cpp

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <fstream>
  #include <string>
  #include <vector>
  #include <chrono>
  #include "Node.h"
  using namespace std;

  long long Hash(string const& str)
  {
  // P and M
  long long p = 63;
  long long m = 1e10 + 9;
  long long x = 1;
  long long haseValue = 0;

  // Loop to calculate the hash value
  // by iterating over the elements of string
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      long long v = 'a';
      haseValue = (haseValue + (str[i] - v + 1) * x) % m;
      x = (x * p) % m;
  }

  //return positive remainder only
  return (haseValue % m + m) % m;
  }

  int main() {

  Node* root = NULL;
  Node node;

  //Prompt the user for file name
  string fileName = "";
  cout << "Please input the file name: ";
  cin >> fileName;
  ifstream myFile(fileName);

  while (!myFile.good()) {
      cout << "Wrong File Name, input again please: ";
      cin >> fileName;
      myFile.open(fileName);
  }

  //create variables
  string id;
  string job_title;
  string email;
  string lastName;
  string firstName;
  string phoneNo;
  string skill;
  string country;

  //INSERTION//
  // create an object of `steady_clock` class
  chrono::steady_clock insertion_timer;
  // start timer
  auto insertion_time_start = insertion_timer.now();

  //Read file
  while (!myFile.eof()) {

      getline(myFile, id, ',');
      getline(myFile, job_title, ',');
      getline(myFile, email, ',');
      getline(myFile, lastName, ',');
      getline(myFile, firstName, ',');
      getline(myFile, phoneNo, ',');
      getline(myFile, skill, ',');
      getline(myFile, country, '\n');

      long long key = Hash(id);
      
      root = node.insert(root, key, id, job_title, email, lastName, firstName, phoneNo, skill, country);
  }
  myFile.close();
  root = node.deleteNode(root, 0);
  // end timer
  auto insertion_time_end = insertion_timer.now();
  // measure time span between start & end
  auto insertion_time_span = static_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(insertion_time_end - insertion_time_start);
  cout << "Insertion: " << insertion_time_span.count() << " seconds" << endl;


  long long targetKey = node.SearchKeybyPhone(root, "2-173-423-8400");
  cout << "target: " << targetKey;

  return 0;
  }
```

Node.cpp

```
using namespace std;

#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>

long long Node::SearchKeybyPhone(Node* root, string phoneNo) {
 if (root != NULL) {
     if (root->phoneNo.compare(phoneNo) == 0) {
         cout << "Expected return value: " << root->key << endl;
         return root->key;    //expected to leave the function and return to main
     }
     SearchKeybyPhone(root->left, phoneNo);
     SearchKeybyPhone(root->right, phoneNo);
 }
}

int Node::getHeight(Node* N)
{
 if (N == NULL)
     return 0;
 return N->height;
}

int Node::max(int a, int b)
{
 return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

Node* Node::newNode(long long key, string id, string job_title, string email, string lastName, string firstName, string phoneNo, string skill, string country)
{
 Node* node = new Node();
 node->key = key;
 node->id = id;
 node->job_title = job_title;
 node->email = email;
 node->lastName = lastName;
 node->firstName = firstName;
 node->phoneNo = phoneNo;
 node->skill = skill;
 node->country = country;
 node->left = NULL;
 node->right = NULL;
 node->height = 1; // new node is initially
                   // added at leaf
 return(node);
}

Node* Node::rightRotate(Node* y)
{
 Node* x = y->left;
 Node* T2 = x->right;

 // Perform rotation
 x->right = y;
 y->left = T2;

 // Update heights
 y->height = max(getHeight(y->left),
     getHeight(y->right)) + 1;
 x->height = max(getHeight(x->left),
     getHeight(x->right)) + 1;

 // Return new root
 return x;
}

Node* Node::leftRotate(Node* x)
{
 Node* y = x->right;
 Node* T2 = y->left;

 // Perform rotation
 y->left = x;
 x->right = T2;

 // Update heights
 x->height = max(getHeight(x->left),
     getHeight(x->right)) + 1;
 y->height = max(getHeight(y->left),
     getHeight(y->right)) + 1;

 // Return new root
 return y;
}

int Node::getBalance(Node* N)
{
 if (N == NULL)
     return 0;
 return getHeight(N->left) -
     getHeight(N->right);
}

Node* Node::insert(Node* node, long long key, string id, string job_title, string email, string lastName, string firstName, string phoneNo, string skill, string country)
{
 /* 1. Perform the normal BST rotation */
 if (node == NULL)
     return(newNode(key, id, job_title, email, lastName, firstName, phoneNo, skill, country));

 if (key < node->key)
     node->left = insert(node->left, key, id, job_title, email, lastName, firstName, phoneNo, skill, country);
 else if (key > node->key)
     node->right = insert(node->right, key, id, job_title, email, lastName, firstName, phoneNo, skill, country);
 else // Equal keys not allowed
     return node;

 /* 2. Update height of this ancestor node */
 node->height = 1 + max(getHeight(node->left),
     getHeight(node->right));

 /* 3. Get the balance factor of this
     ancestor node to check whether
     this node became unbalanced */
 int balance = getBalance(node);

 // If this node becomes unbalanced,
 // then there are 4 cases

 // Left Left Case
 if (balance > 1 && key < node->left->key)
     return rightRotate(node);

 // Right Right Case
 if (balance < -1 && key > node->right->key)
     return leftRotate(node);

 // Left Right Case
 if (balance > 1 && key > node->left->key)
 {
     node->left = leftRotate(node->left);
     return rightRotate(node);
 }

 // Right Left Case
 if (balance < -1 && key < node->right->key)
 {
     node->right = rightRotate(node->right);
     return leftRotate(node);
 }

 /* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
 return node;
}

Node* Node::minValueNode(Node* node)
{
 Node* current = node;

 /* loop down to find the leftmost leaf */
 while (current->left != NULL)
     current = current->left;

 return current;
}

Node* Node::deleteNode(Node* root, long long key)
{
 // STEP 1: PERFORM STANDARD BST DELETE
 if (root == NULL)
     return root;

 // If the key to be deleted is smaller
 // than the root's key, then it lies
 // in left subtree
 if (key < root->key)
     root->left = deleteNode(root->left, key);

 // If the key to be deleted is greater
 // than the root's key, then it lies
 // in right subtree
 else if (key > root->key)
     root->right = deleteNode(root->right, key);

 // if key is same as root's key, then
 // This is the node to be deleted
 else
 {
     // node with only one child or no child
     if ((root->left == NULL) ||
         (root->right == NULL))
     {
         Node* temp = root->left ?
             root->left :
             root->right;

         // No child case
         if (temp == NULL)
         {
             temp = root;
             root = NULL;
         }
         else // One child case
             *root = *temp; // Copy the contents of
                            // the non-empty child
         free(temp);
     }
     else
     {
         // node with two children: Get the inorder
         // successor (smallest in the right subtree)
         Node* temp = minValueNode(root->right);

         // Copy the inorder successor's
         // data to this node
         root->key = temp->key;

         // Delete the inorder successor
         root->right = deleteNode(root->right,
             temp->key);
     }
 }

 // If the tree had only one node
 // then return
 if (root == NULL)
     return root;

 // STEP 2: UPDATE HEIGHT OF THE CURRENT NODE
 root->height = 1 + max(getHeight(root->left),
     getHeight(root->right));

 // STEP 3: GET THE BALANCE FACTOR OF
 // THIS NODE (to check whether this
 // node became unbalanced)
 int balance = getBalance(root);

 // If this node becomes unbalanced,
 // then there are 4 cases

 // Left Left Case
 if (balance > 1 &&
     getBalance(root->left) >= 0)
     return rightRotate(root);

 // Left Right Case
 if (balance > 1 &&
     getBalance(root->left) < 0)
 {
     root->left = leftRotate(root->left);
     return rightRotate(root);
 }

 // Right Right Case
 if (balance < -1 &&
     getBalance(root->right) <= 0)
     return leftRotate(root);

 // Right Left Case
 if (balance < -1 &&
     getBalance(root->right) > 0)
 {
     root->right = rightRotate(root->right);
     return leftRotate(root);
 }

 return root;
}

void Node::preOrder(Node* root)
{
 if (root != NULL)
 {
     cout << root->key << " ";
     preOrder(root->left);
     preOrder(root->right);
 }
}
```

Node.h

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
   long long key;
   string id;
   string job_title;
   string email;
   string lastName;
   string firstName;
   string phoneNo;
   string skill;
   string country;
   Node* left;
   Node* right;
   int height;

   int getHeight(Node* N);
   int max(int a, int b);
   Node* newNode(long long key, string id, string job_title, string email, string lastName, string firstName, string phoneNo, string skill, string country);
   Node* rightRotate(Node* y);
   Node* leftRotate(Node* x);
   int getBalance(Node* N);
   Node* insert(Node* node, long long key, string id, string job_title, string email, string lastName, string firstName, string phoneNo, string skill, string country);
   Node* minValueNode(Node* node);
   Node* deleteNode(Node* root, long long key);
   void preOrder(Node* root);
   long long SearchKeybyPhone(Node* root, string phoneNo);
};
#endif
```

Comment: What you need to do is debug. Place print statements at different places or use a debugger tool to see why you get an unexpected result.

Comment: `SearchKeybyPhone(root->left, phoneNo);` one obvious issue I see is that you are calling the function recursively but not storing/checking its result.

Comment: Off-topic: About [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...

Comment: `Node* Node::newNode` – this is what a *constructor* is for, you should rather convert to one (`Node::Node(/*parameters*/)`) – and if we are at that already, consider the constructors initialiser list right away (not to be confused with `std::initializer_list`): `Node::Node(...) : memberA(someValue), memberB(anotherValue) { }` (this prefers direct initialisation by value over default initialisation + assignment; additionally some types – references, constant members, non-default-constructible types, ... – *only* can be initialised that way...).

Comment: Continuing on @kiner_shah 's comment: You don't have a return value for the root being null either. If you don't find the phone number what would you want to return? Is there a validly usable sentinel value within the range of `long long`? If not, which is likely, you might want to consider another return type, e.g. `std::pair<bool, long long>` such that the boolean indicates if the value has been found at all, or `std::optional`. Then try to phrase the algorithm in normal English: Search left sub-tree, ***if*** the value has been found, return it, otherwise try right sub-tree...

Comment: Geeksforgeeks is not a particularly good place to learn from. It's not worth what you're paying for it.

Comment: Need to agree on @molbdnilo – while you indeed *can* find quite a few good examples there you'll encounter at the same time pretty often low quality code, sometimes with absolute no-goes in there (like [including `bits/stdc++.h`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)). It will render difficult for a beginner to distinguish them...

Comment: Thanks all of you, I finished debuging

Comment: @Edison1235, if you already have a solution to your problem, you can self-answer your question.